Implicit solution curve of ODE = solution without time dependence
I've been reading Hale's Ordinary Differential Equations book and stumbled upon a section that I do not understand. It is about autonomous systems. I'll give some the definitions  from Hale and the lemma I have questions about.
We have a differential equation (1)
\begin{equation}
\dot{x} = f(x),
\end{equation}
where $f:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is continuous and $\Omega$ is open. We denote solution to (1) as $\phi(t,p)$, where $\phi(0,p) = 0$. We assume that the solution is continuous and unique. We define orbit as $\gamma(p) = \{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: \text{there exists t}\in \mathbb{R} \text{ and map (solution) } \phi \text{ such that } \phi(t,p)= x \}$.
A curve $\lambda$ is a range of a continuous mapping of an interval $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ into $\mathbb{R}^n$. The curve is said to be differentiable if the associated mapping is differentiable. Given $f = (f_1, \dots, f_n)$ as above, we say that a curve $\lambda$ is a solution of the equations (2)
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx_1}{f_1(x)} = 
\frac{dx_2}{f_2(x)} = \dots = 
\frac{dx_n}{f_n(x)},
\end{equation}
if $\lambda$ is differentiable and the differential $dx$ along $\lambda$ is parallel to $f(x)$ when $f(x) \neq 0$, and $\lambda$ is a point when $f(x) = 0$.
By critical point $p\in \mathbb{R}^n$ we mean a root of right hand side ($f(p) = 0$).
Now comes the lemma along with Hale's proof.
The solution of (2) at any point p of $\Omega$ is the orbit of (1) through $p$.
Proof. If $p = (p_1, \dots, p_n)$ is a critical point, then $\gamma$ and $\lambda$ are both equal to $p$. If $p$ is not a critical point, then one of the components of $f$, say $f_1$ is such that $f_1(x)=0$. Therefore $f_1(x)\neq 0$ for $x$ in a neighborhood $U$ of $p$. In $U$ system (2) is therefore equivalent to the ordinary differential system (3)
\begin{align}
&\frac{dx_{\alpha}}{dx_1} = \frac{f_{\alpha}(x)}{f_1(x)}, & x_{\alpha}(p_1) = p_{\alpha}, & \text{ and }\alpha = 2, 3, \dots, n.
\end{align}
From exitence theorem (suffices to have continuous $f$ and we assume throughout uniqueness of solution) there exists a solution $x_{\alpha}(x_1)$ to (3) for $|x_1-p_1|$ sufficiently small. We parametrize $\lambda$ in the following way. Consider autonomous scalar equation (4)
\begin{equation}
\frac{dx_1}{dt} = f_1(x_1, x_2(x_1), \dots, x_n(x_1)).
\end{equation}
This equation has a solution $x_1(t)$, $x_1(0) = p_1$ for $|t|$ small. One now easily shows that $x_1(t)$, $x_{\alpha}(x_1(t))$, $\alpha = 2, \dots, n$ is a solution of (1). Since the orbit of (1) through any point of $\Omega$ is a solution of (2), this proves $\lambda = \gamma$ and the lemma.
My questions:
a) I didn't really comprehend what does equation (2) mean. Is it just a special way to write equations for $f_j(x) \neq 0 $, $\frac{dx_{\alpha}}{dx_j} = \frac{f_{\alpha}(x)}{f_j(x)}$, $\alpha \neq j$ and solution is $p$, if $f(p) = 0$? Or is there some math that cannot be skipped to explain the lemma (I did not learn differential forms nor differential geometry)?
b) (Core question): Consider now $p$ not critical. In the lemma, I understand that "locally", on some small neighborhood of $0$ for $t$ and on some small neighborhood of $x_1$, the solutions $x(t)$ and $x'(x_1) = (x_1, x_2(x_1), \dots, x_n(x_1))$  must match. What I do not understand is the following. Take maximal interval of existence for $x(t)$, say $I$ and maximal interval of existence for $x'(x_1)$, say $I_1$ (if $f_1(x) = 0$, take $f(x_2)\neq 0$ in (3) to get solution $x'(x_2)$ on maximal interval of existence $I_2$ and so on until $n$). How can I show equality $\{x(t) : t\in I\} = \{x'(x_1) : x_1\in I_1\} \cup \{x'(x_2) : x_2\in I_2\} \cup \dots \cup\{x'(x_n) : x_n\in I_n\}$ (5)? I.e. question c). I suppose that this extension from "local" to the whole interval of existence comes from uniqueness but I don't see how. I do not see how any of the inclusions in equality (5) work outside of this "local" settings.
c) (Rephrasing question b) for clarity): Now exclude possibility of $p$ being critical. Does the lemma say that we can obtain non-parametrized solution (to its full extent - the maximal solution) by solving implicit problem (of course changing the respective implicit equation (3) according to which component is not zero - all of them cannot be zero at the same time due to uniqueness).
Thanks for any help! (I know this is a really long question).
